# How can I omit a specific comma from my output?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, scripting

I wanted to format my output using awk/sed, but I can't understand how to do it. I am using following command:

```
uptime | awk '{print $1" " $2" " $3$4" " $6" " $10$11$12}' 
15:36:17 up 177days, 7 0.39,0.43,0.36
```

My desired output is

```
15:36:17 up 177days 7 0.39,0.43,0.36
```

I wanted to omit only first comma, i.e. the one after "177days".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either `sub` (substitute the comma with the empty string) or `substr` (make a substring with all but the last character):

```
uptime | awk '{sub(",","",$4); print $1" " $2" " $3$4" " $6" " $10$11$12}'

uptime | awk '{print $1" " $2" " $3 substr($4,1,length($4)-1) " " $6" " $10$11$12}'
```

Comment: Thanks @jas    `uptime | awk '{sub(",","",$4); print $1" " $2" " $3$4" " $6" " $10$11$12}'`  It's working perfectly.       However 2nd command is not working on my machine.

Comment: Hmm, for me it works with both `awk` and `gawk` --- what's happening? Are you getting an error or unexpected output?

Comment: It was blank output, not showing anything. @ jas you said abt ’ gawk’  , is 2nd command is for gawk?

Comment: Nothing specific to gawk here (I'm using plain awk on Mac OS X). Strange that you would get no output and no error. You copied and pasted exactly from the answer? Didn't miss any opening or closing quotes? (Sorry to ask so obvious things but it's a real mystery.)

Comment: Yes @jas , I pasted exactly from the answer...but didn't get any output.

Comment: Shoot, well, at this point since I can't reproduce it I can't really help much more. If you care enough you can open a new question "Why no output from awk statement", e.g. or you can just use what works and not worry about it for now. I leave it to you!

Comment: Thanks @jas for your suggestion. Actually I got my desired result from your 1st command.

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the output of your command to a `sed` that'll match any alphabetic character followed by a comma and replace it with that character:

```
uptime | awk '{print $1" " $2" " $3$4" " $6" " $10$11$12}' | sed -r 's/(\w),/\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks @lelkadi, It's also working perfectly. As I am new in here , can u please explain me `\w` and `\1` from this `sed -r 's/(\w),/\1/'` ? It'll definitely help me a lot.

Comment: `\w` matches any word character, and since to embedded in the `()` the match will be capture as the group number 1, and can be accessed using the `\1`. So the above regex matches a word character followed by a comma `,`, then replaces them with the captured character only `\1`.

Comment: Thanks @lelkadi for your explanation.